# Perl passing data to stdin and reading from stdout and stderr

Tags: c, xml, perl

There might be many questions available here regarding the same, but none works for me as of now.

I've a C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

long size(FILE *st_in) {
    struct stat st;
    if (fstat(fileno(st_in), &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;
    return -1;
}

int main (){
   FILE *file = stdin;
   long s1, s2; 

   s1 = size(file);
   printf("Size is %ld\n", s1);
   fprintf(stderr, "%d", 1);
   return 0;
}
```

I compile it as an output a.out.

I've an xml file 'sample.xml'

```
<sample>
    <tag>Hello</tag>
    <tag>Cool</tag>
</sample>
```

Then I've this perl code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use IPC::Open2;
open FILE, "sample.xml" or die $!;
my @xmlfile = <FILE>;
my $pid = open2(*Reader, *Writer, "./a.out");
print Writer "@xmlfile";
waitpid($pid, 0);
my @got = <Reader>;
close Writer;
close Reader;
close $pid;
print "Output got is\n";
print @got;
```

If I run the C program passing simple.xml via stdin, I get the following:

```
[bharath@xml 18:22:34]$ ./a.out < sample.xml 
Size is 60
```

When I run the perl code, I expect the size as 60. But I get as 0.

```
[bharath@xml 18:22:42]$ ./firmware.pl 
Output got is
Size is 0
```

So how do I solve this? I need to pass the sample.xml from an @array in perl. And the stderr integer from the C program should get stored in a separate variable and the stdout from the C program should get stored in another separate variable in perl. I think this might require using open3 but I don't know how to use. Any working example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help if you close `Writer` before the `waitpid`?  That seemed to help here, although I cannot precisely reproduce (did not try too precisely, either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: as for your comments Ilmari Karonen already explained you that a pipe doesn't have a filesize because it's a stream of data, the program doesn't know how big this stream could be.

You've two problems: your C program is not working and also your Perl program is not working because it goes in a deadlock. You can't test the two things together. Separate the two problems. For instance first try your program with the pipe from the shell.

```
cat sample.xml | ./a.out 
Size is 60
```

Originally it wasn't working. To make it work I've used this modified C program: the size could be calculated from the stream by counting all received chars until EOF.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    long size = 0;
    int ch;
    FILE *file = stdin;
    if (!file) {
        return 2;
    }
    while ((ch = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        ++size;
    }
    printf("Size is %ld\n", size);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

As for your Perl program you had a deadlock because both programs were in wait state, to solve it I've changed slightly the order of the instructions:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use IPC::Open2;

open FILE, "sample.xml" or die $!;
my @xmlfile = <FILE>;

my $pid = open2(*Reader, *Writer, './a.out 2> /dev/null');
print Writer @xmlfile;
close(Writer);

my @got = <Reader>;
close(Reader);
waitpid($pid, 0);

print "Output got is: ";
print @got;
```

As you can see I close the writer, before I start to read because my C program is designed to get all the input and then do the output. And now the whole interprocess communication will work:

```
./program.pl
Output got is: Size is 60
```

As a side note you don't need to close $pid, since is just a number representing the process id of the child. In other cases you might want to explore [non blocking reads](http://davesource.com/Solutions/20080924.Perl-Non-blocking-Read-On-Pipes-Or-Files.html), but will make the logic more complicated.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: didn't solve the poster problem because he wanted to use IPC.

Can you just add the filename as sample.xml to the $cmd? You could just use the backtick operator to capture the output, chomp removes the newline and the output will be in $out.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$cmd = './a.out < sample.xml 2> /dev/null';
$out = `$cmd`;
chomp $out;
print "out='$out'\n";
```

I guess that your example is to find a way to communicate between C and Perl, because of course, if it's just for the file size it's much easier in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print -s 'sample.xml';
print "\n";
```

Comment: Well the intention is not that. Just that this is a stripped out version of a much larger problem. I have certain C programs which needs to be called via perl and I need to pass xml 'data' to the C program. The xml data is got in an array in perl. To demonstrate this I'm reading it from a file here.

Comment: Got you, fixed with IPC communication, you had a problem both in the C and in the Perl part.

Comment: Appreciate your effort @stivlo. I need to get the size before reading the xml as I would use that to malloc an array of that size and put the xml contents inside that. So If I use getc, I lose the data. The xml contents will be processed further from the dynamically generated array.

Comment: then pass it from Perl, because it's the only one who can know the size. You can pass it in the stream as the first line.

Comment: Thanks! I've selected this as most suitable answer! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the problem is not in your Perl code, but in the C program.  Try running

```
cat sample.xml | ./a.out
```

in shell, and you should get the same output as from your Perl program.  The problem is that, in both cases, `stdin` will be a pipe instead of a file, and `fstat()` obviously can't return any meaningful size for a pipe.

In any case, calling `fstat()` on `stdin` seems like bad practice to me — you shouldn't be relying on what is essentially an optimization made by the shell.  The only real guarantee you get about `stdin` is that you can (try to) read data from it; other than that, it might be anything: a file, a pipe, a tty, etc.

Comment: yes, you're right: $ ./a.out < sample.xml
Size is 60
  $ cat sample.xml | ./a.out 
Size is 0

Comment: Hi @limari Karonen. What you suggested is a very good point. As commented above, I have certain C programs which needs to be called via perl and I need to pass xml 'data' to the C program. The xml data is got in an array in perl. What would be the best approach to transfer the data? How should the C program get the input? The size of the data is variable. Also I need to get the value of stdout, stderr in separate variables in perl.

Comment: @Bharathwaaj: Does your XML parser really need the input in a single string?  Most I've seen are happy to read the XML in chunks from an input stream.